After migration: tables name not suit the created table name
I am using drizzle as orm in my project. When I want to create a table, I have name it like:
    `export const messages = createTable("msg", {
  id: bigint("id", { mode: "number" }).primaryKey().autoincrement(),
  content: text("content").notNull(),
  senderId: varchar("sender_id", { length: 255 }).notNull().references(() => users.id),
  receiverId: varchar("receiver_id", { length: 255 }).notNull().references(() => users.id),
  conversationId: varchar("conversation_id", { length: 255 }).notNull(),
  createdAt: timestamp("created_at").default(sql`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`).notNull(),
  updatedAt: timestamp("updated_at").default(sql`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`).onUpdateNow(),
});`

But why after migrating, the tables name in my database is like this realtime-chat-app_message, it always add the realtime-chat-app there.
Here is my drizzle config:
    `import { type Config } from "drizzle-kit";

import { env } from "@/env";

export default {
  schema: "./src/server/db/schema.ts",
  dialect: "mysql",
  dbCredentials: {
    url: env.DATABASE_URL,
  },
} satisfies Config;
`


I have remove  tablesFilter: ["realtime-chat-app_*"] from the drizzle config, but still the same. Nothing change at all.
